# Tableau online how to integrate numerous views into one

Tags: tableau-api

I am using Tableau public desktop - the free version.  I am trying to place multiple worksheets, and dashboards on one page and link it to my blog site. 
Is there a way to customize views in this application? Something like this:

https://public.tableau.com/views/CountyGuide-Demographics_0/DemographicsAll?%3Aembed=y&%3Ahost_url=%2F%2Fpublic.tableausoftware.com%2F&%3AshowVizHome=no&%3Ascrolling=no&%3Atabs=no&%3Atoolbar=yes&%3Aanimate_transition=yes&%3Adisplay_static_image=yes&%3Adisplay_spinner=yes&%3Adisplay_overlay=yes&%3Adisplay_count=no&%3AloadOrderID=0#3

Or does it require a subscription to accomplish this feat? Is there a workaround for if not?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

All the cool stuff WRT layout/navigation in the sample link you posted are possible in Tableau Public. 
You don't need subscription for creating dashboards and adding actions for navigation etc.

You can see [Tableau Tutorials](https://www.tableau.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/building-dashboard) for details.